# How to replace part of a string based on a group of letters in the matched string?

Tags: html, regex, gulp, sublimetext3

I have a bunch of HTML files that have classes that need to be updated, and the content between the tags removed. In plain English, here is the pattern:

The text,

`<i class="ss-icon">joystick</i>`

needs to be replaced with

`<i class="ss-joystick"></i>`

Where 'joystick' could be any string with no spaces or special characters. If this can be done in Sublime Text's find/replace fields, that would be great. Otherwise, I've been looking into Gulp packages that could do the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I've tried reading about capturing groups, and I think I'm on the right track, but I really am not familiar enough with regex to know what to do. I'm at a "will it take longer to learn it or to do it by hand?" point.

Comment: You can let somebody else do it for you (such as the answer below), or you can go and learn about regex and better yourself as a programmer :)  I'd do the latter... definitely.  Then you don't have to waste your time writing up questions like this - you could just solve it yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code :

```
regex=/(.*class=\'ss-)(.*?)(\'>)(.*?)(<\/.*)/;
str="<i class='ss-icon'>joystick</i>";
var newStr=str.replace(regex, "$1$4$3$5");
console.log(newStr); //<i class='ss-joystick'></i>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yehiaawad/Lbnde5nh/

Comment: Is there a reason this got downvoted? This is the right answer for me.

Comment: Lol nevermind some people can't handle competition )